# asp.net c# ExecuteReader() error

Tags: c#, asp.net, executereader

The following code produces an error.
dbo.getit works fine when I call it directly on the server.  The error occurs at cmd.ExecuteReader() .  What am I doing wrong?

```
    string user;
    string pw;
    SqlDataReader dr = null;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=myDB;    Integrated Security=True");

    user = Username.Text.Trim();
    pw = Password.Text.Trim();

    conn.Open();

   try {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.getit", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", user);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", pw);

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while ( dr.Read() )
        {
            Session["username"] = user;
            // Session["admin"] = 
            // Session["completed"] =
            Server.Transfer("all_is_well.aspx");

        }
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (dr != null)
        {
            dr.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
        Server.Transfer("ERROR.aspx");
    }
```

SOLUTION:
Replace the two corresponding lines above with these:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.getit(@param1, @param2);", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.text;
```

Comment: The error is due to a bug. Be more specific about the error, and we'll be in a better position to be more specific about the bug... aka, please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit your question.

Comment: usually the Exception ex has a Message and a StackTrace.. please put a breakpoint, read and post this informations to have the possibility to find the reason of the error.

Comment: I'm unable to use a break point in the environment I'm using.  I'll try to print the error to the web page somehow.

Comment: before Server.Transfer save the exception in Session, then in Error.aspx read the session and propmt the error..

Comment: ahhh, Emanuele, tx.  seems obvious once you tell me.  I see it can't find the stored procedure.  That's odd, since I used the same sql in a VB version of this program I wrote a few weeks back. tx, i think I can figure it out from here.

Comment: I switched the sql from "select * from dbo.getit" to just "getit" and I get "The request for procedure 'getit' failed because 'getit' is a table valued function object."

I don't understand, because I thought the whole purpose of the reader was to get the result of a table valued function.

Comment: Code is working now.  Thanks for help everyone.  All comments were useful.  Especially thanks for the technique, Emanuele ... my devel env is extremely limited and I have no control.  My solution was   sql = "select * from dbo.findUserPW(@param1, @param2);"
and 
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
I don't know why my previous stuff failed, but this works, so I'm going on to next thing.  Thanks a bunch.  Don't know which solution to check below ... neither was the answer, but they were both helpful...really,tx, tff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:
Replace the two corresponding lines above with these:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.getit(@param1, @param2);", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.text;
```

That worked.

Answer (score 2):

This just seems questionable,

```
Session["username"] = user; 
Server.Transfer("all_is_well.aspx");
```

inside the while loop!

Can you at least finish iterating on the reader, using a temporary object to store the result of the query, and then initialize you session and do the `Server.Transfer`. .

Comment: Isn't Server.Transfer known to throw a `ThreadAbortException`

Comment: Agree inside the while loop, worse case OP could set a bool indicating userFound = true. Then after the reader finishes, if (userFound) do the server transfer, doing the server transfer inside a loop is pretty ponderous.

Comment: i don't think is this the problem: a reader is executed, but the code written there is not executed.. it was just useless sample code to test the program.

Comment: Avoid Server.Transfer because of the ThreadAbortException which can cause all kinds of unexpected [behavior](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2010/Jan/20/HttpContextItems-and-ServerTransferExecute). Also [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Server.Transfer ***terminates*** execution of the current page and starts execution of a new page for the current request. Also, Transfer calls **End**, which throws a **ThreadAbortException** exception upon completion.

I think what you are trying to do (*and I am answering based on what you are trying to do - not necessarily best pratice*) is verify that the user is authorized/authenticated in some way based on a data store. You'd be better off not using ExecuteReader at all. Use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx). If the result of ExecuteScalar is not null, the user was found.

```
if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() != null)
{
   Server.Transfer("all_is_well.aspx");
}

else
{
   Server.Transfer("someErrorPage.aspx");
}
```

Comment: I think that's the right way to do this, given my starting point; however, that's not my error.  For some reason it gives an error on the excecutescalar ... I'm experimenting with different sql right now.

Part of the problem is I'm switching from using a dataadapter which worked perfectly (at least in vb) to using a datareader.  

sql = "dbo.getit";
sql = "dbo.getit(@param1, @param2);";
sql = "select * from dbo.getit(@param1, @param2);";

etc.